# php - resizing image and upload it via ftp

Tags: php

Trying to resample one image and upload(reupload) it to my server via ftp.
I've ftp access, so no conection problems here, but my file doesn't go there because imagecopyresized handle is a number (1) and not a file.

The question is, what should i do with this litle code

```
imagejpeg($background,ftp_put($conn_id, $destino, imagecopyresized($background, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h), FTP_BINARY),99);
```

Thanks,

Pluda

Comment: Save the image to a file first, and then upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ftp_put - third parameter for this function must be path to local file.

So you should save image to local and then try to use ftp_put function

```
$local_file = '/tmp/temp.jpg';

if ( imagecopyresized($background, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h) ) 
{
    if ( imagejpeg($background, $local_file) ) 
    {
        if ( ftp_put($conn_id, $destino, $local_file, FTP_BINARY) ) 
        {
            unlink($local_file)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, but can I have access to user local hd? This is a webbased application, the file to be resized is already in my server, just need to be able to 'edit' it, read the image, make the adjustment and resave it. I'm trying all these sugestions but none seems to be working... now I'm getting one "No such file or directory" but the file is there, I'm sure :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not geting what you mean, the image is saved on my pics folder (in webserver). Then I try to resample (maybe I don't need to upload, image is already in webserver...) just need to resave image with same name, is that?

Comment: First you should read your image data.
Then you should resize it (imagecopyresized).
Then you should save resized image to you webserver (of course you can replace your image), but your php process should have write permission on directory where you will save it.
Then you use   ftp_put  function for uploading resized image.
P.S. sorry i send previous comment before write it all =)

Comment: Thank you, your solution is good, my mistake was I was using full paths, like http://www.domain/folder/file  (this doesn't work ), but with relative paths like  ../folder/file  it works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

save that image to file and then send it

```
$servername = "8.8.8.8";
$ftpUser = "user";
$ftpPass = "pass";
$conn = ftp_connect($servername) or die("Error connecting to $servername");

if(ftp_login($conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPass))
{
            ftp_put($conn_id, "image.jpg", $file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an output buffer to capture the output of `imagejpeg` and the send it in ftp:

```
imagecopyresized($background, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($background, NULL, 99);
$background = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();

ftp_put($conn_id, $destino, $background, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't work... "PHP Warning:  ftp_put(\xff\xd8\xff\xe0) [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory"